# How to show resolved SCSS names in WebStorm

Tags: css, sass, webstorm

I'm new to WebStorm, having come from VS Code. In my SCSS files in VS Code, if I hover the mouse over the second line in the following code:

```
.example {
  table button.abc:hover {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

A popup appears as so:

```
<element class="example">
  ...
    <table>
      ...
        <button class="abc" :hover>
```

I've found this to be an extremely helpful feature when working with complicated nested CSS rules, as I can see at a glance how it's being resolved. Does WebStorm (or any plugin for it) provide a feature like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature, please vote for [WEB-35464](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35464) to be notified on any progress with this request